# extracting multiples of given value from vector

Tags: matlab, vector

From the following vector:

```
depth = [0:0.1:20];
```

How could I create a new vector that had the same data as 'depth' but a value taken every 0.5, providing an outcome of:

```
d2 = depth(1:5:end);
```

Since my data is not actually spaced at 0.1 intervals but at random intervals I cannot apply the simple approach shown above. What would be the best methods of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find the closest points in the array to a linearly spaced grid, you can do it like this:

```
% some example data
A = zeros(40,1);
for ii = 2:numel(A); A(ii)=A(ii-1)+rand; end

% your linear grid
Linds = A(1) : 0.5 : A(end);

% nearest indices
[~,inds] = min( abs(bsxfun(@minus, A, Linds)) );
```

Note that entries in `inds` might be repeated. Otherwise, if you want to do an interpolation in your vector, you need `interp1`. From the documentation:

> YI = INTERP1(X,Y,XI) interpolates to find YI, the values of the
>       underlying function Y at the points in the array XI. X must be a
>       vector of length N.

Note that multiple different interpolation kernels are available, e.g., `'linear'`, `'spline'`, etc. Consult `help interp1` for more info.

Comment: this really wont do for my problem, I am attempting to find the uncertainty of interpolation methods as my overall aim therefore this will not work. Isn't there a method for using the first value of the array and then select every + 0.5 thereafter?

Comment: @Kate you mentioned that the intervals are random. What would you pick if there is no sample at the desired interval?

Comment: By random intervals I meant that they are not spaced at 0.1, they will be spaced at 0.002, 0.034, 0,3, etc. If there is not value at a specified multiple of 0.5 then I wish to find the closest value.